# Spring adding mvc:resources tag

Tags: java, xml, spring

Here is my dispatcher file. I have added the namespace for schema/mvc, content and their corresponding location...

Now, when I run my application using the below xml I get page not found for my application but when I remove the xmlns:mvc and resources tag it works without any problem...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    ">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.school.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
             <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
          </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/static/" />
```

URL - `http://localhost:8080/SchoolManagement/`

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet -

```
package com.school.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.school.beans.Login;

@Controller
public class Logincontroller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student() {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "loginform", new Login());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/static/" />
```

This tag basically says that if path in the URI starts with "/resources/" then return files located in "/resources/static/"

Check that your files (pictures, css and so on) are locatled in `<your_webapp_root>/resources/static/`

EDIT:

I also noticed your are using different versions in your name space declaration:

```
spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
spring-beans-2.5.xsd
spring-context-2.5.xsd
```

Check your dependencies and use correct version